# If string/pattern is found then remove it from the list

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a JSON file which I am retrieving from a MongoDB Database using `PyMongo`.

I have converted the Python cursor into a list by doing the following:

```
db = mongo_client.test_db
table = db.test_table
doc = list(table.find())
```

Now what I am trying to do is check whether the list contains a particular string, and if it does it should only keep a substring of the string.

**List:**

```
doc=[{'_id': ObjectId('5f45228293d7b757bcbd2d67'),'features': [DBRef('featId', ObjectId('5f452e3793d7b757bcbd2d88'))]}]
```

So currently I am using the code below to check whether `DBRef` exists within the list which works fine.
But I'm not quite sure what to replace the print statement with, in order to keep only the `ObjectId`.

```
if "DBRef" in str(doc):
    print("its here") #remove the dbref and only keep alphanumeric value
else:
    print("not here") #do nothing to the list
```

**Expected Output (if DBRef found in the list):**

```
doc=[{'_id': ObjectId('5f45228293d7b757bcbd2d67'),'features': ObjectId('5f452e3793d7b757bcbd2d88')}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you have a dictionary inside a list, therefore you could just update some of it's values.

Not sure what is your desired output for the doc variable, how many dicts are in the list and etc, however, here is what I came up with:

1. Find a value, that needs to be saved with regex or just by referring to the object id
2. Create temp dict with required key:value pair
3. Update your existing dict inside the list

doc[0] is referring to the first element of a list.

'''python

Option 1:

```
#regex version in case saving ObjectId as bson.objectid is not required

import re

object_value = re.search("DBRef\('featId', ObjectId\((.*?)\)", str(doc[0]['features'])).group(1)
d1 = {'features': f'ObjectId({object_value})'}
doc[0].update(d1)
```

Option 2:

```
#accessing the required value directly and saving it as ObjectId
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson.dbref import DBRef

object_value_no_regex = doc[0]['features'][0].id
d1 = {'features': ObjectId(object_value_no_regex)}
doc[0].update(d1)
```

Thanks!